# [flutter]statelessWidget? statefulWidget?

Tags: flutter

I`m studying about statelessWidget, statefulWidget.

below is what I studied:

state : data that affect to UI.

UI : All visual elements visible to the user

I want to make UI that have no changes while app is running -> statelessWidget

I want to make UI that have changes while app is running -> statefulWidget

---

Then, can I say that the wave effect appears when click the elevatedButton is the change of UI?
Can I say that the UI has changed when I enter the texts in the textField?
I am curious even these minor changes are considered changes of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

A widget is a view of model data.  The data can be from three sources: the constructor arguments, observable external data (Change notifiers and other Listenables), and mutable internal state.  If a widget does not need mutable internal state, it does not need to be a StatefulWidget... however it might still change as the result of changed dependencies (Listenables and children).

Answer (score 0):

It is the change in state data, which will change the UI.

I want to make a widget that has no state data changes while the app is running -> StatelessWidget

I want to make a widget that has state data changes while the app is running -> StatefulWidget

The wave effect when clicking on the elevatedButton does not change data, hence we use StatelessWidget

Entering text in the TextField changes the data inside the TextField, so we use StatefulWidget

Comment: See my answer.  You forget Listenables and children as sources of change.